# HTML5 canvas Showing lines when drawing

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, jstilemap

I have a Problem when drawing tile-map and setting the tile width to `$(window).width() / 10` and the tile height to `$(window).height() / 10`

The canvas drawing additional lines between every tile

Here's the code: https://jsfiddle.net/t68sgrf3/

Comment: Seems like a rounding issue. Ensure the canvas height & width is set to a number divisible by 10.

Comment: @junvar Do you know how to automatically set canvas height&width to a number divisible by 10

Comment: `<canvas width=1000 height=1000></canvas>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example with a canvas of 500x503 dimensions. Notice the height is not divisible by 10, so we get incorrect horizontal lines of the background showing through. Whereas the width is divisible by 10, and we see no such vertical lines.

```js
let canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

let width = canvas.width / 10;
let height = canvas.height / 10;
console.log(width, height);

ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

for (let x = 0; x < 10; x++)
  for (let y = 0; y < 10; y++) {
    ctx.fillStyle = (x + y) % 2 ? '#ffe' : '#eef';
    ctx.fillRect(x * width, y * height, width, height);
  }
```

```css
canvas {
  outline: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<canvas width=500 height=503></canvas>
```